# jQuery Skitter Slideshow error

Tags: jquery, object, slideshow, skitter-slider

I have a problem with [jQuery Skitter Slideshow](http://thiagosf.net/projects/jquery/skitter/). It doesn't work!
I found one error with Element inspector of my browser: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'skitter'`
The test is here: *[obscured]*
What is the problem?

Comment: For a moment there, I saw "Jon Skeet" in the title.

Comment: Me too, and he gave a slideshow error :-D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi (ciao) It was a nightmare...but I included step by step all your js files; and found the problem.

Skitter stop working after the including of query.tools.min; the reason is because you're including jQuery again with it (the new definition erases any plugins, since it re-defined the jquery object).

Here is a working fiddle before: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/jV6qy/5/

And the same after the include: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/jV6qy/6/

To solve the problem instead of this:

```
http://www.ajyalitalia.it/testwp/wp-content/themes/polaris/js/jquery.tools.min.js
```

include this:

```
http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/all/jquery.tools.min.js
```

Here is the final working version: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/jV6qy/7/

Comment: Thank you very much Edward,
Thanks for your excellent explanation! :) and forgive me if you spend your time to resolve my problem. Thank you!